# Oracle table expression on collection and order

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am analyzing some existing PL\SQL code and I can see cases where Oracle collections are unnested in queries using table expressions.

There is no order clause and the code obviously assumes that the items will be returned in the order as they are stored in the collection. 
I know that you cannot assume order of items returned by select if there is no "order by", but in this case it seems to work.

Example code:

```
create type s_table as table of varchar2(100);

select rownum, t.* from table(s_table('TERM1', 'TERM2', 'TERM3')) t
```

Should I worry and change the code ?

Comment: I don't succeed to "unsort" them, even with parallel(t 8). This construction is pure pl/sql and it iterate it sequentialy, so the order is keeped. But I don't guaratee on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No ORDER BY = no order guarantee

And here is an example that proves the fact, that the order of the elements in the collection is not necessarily the order according to which the elements could appear 
in other queries based on the given collection object.

```
 SQL> CREATE TYPE str_nestab_ty AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(20);
 2  /

 Type created.

 SQL> SELECT COLUMN_VALUE
 2  FROM TABLE(
 3                CAST
 4                (
 5                    MULTISET
 6                    (
 7                        SELECT 'e10' AS strval FROM DUAL UNION
 8                        SELECT 'e07' AS strval FROM DUAL UNION
 9                        SELECT 'e04' AS strval FROM DUAL UNION
10                        SELECT 'e20' AS strval FROM DUAL UNION
11                        SELECT 'e14' AS strval FROM DUAL
12                    )
13                    AS str_nestab_ty
14                )
15             );

   COLUMN_VALUE
--------------------
e04
e07
e10
e14
e20

SQL>
```

Comment: Yes, I agree, "no order = no order guarantee" the problem is that the code has been in production for some time and in simpler case it works. But I see that it may stop to work so I am going to replace it gradually. Thanks for your example.

Comment: I don't see why this is a valid counter-example. The ordering here has nothing to do with the nested table, it's just a result of the UNION clauses.