# Select rows and keep order of text in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have a lot of text data that I must use as a key to return other data from the database. The problem is that some of those keys dont exist. They query I am looking for should return empty rows for them

```
select column1, column2,column3 from mobilenumbers where mobile_number in ('123456789','123456798');
```

So far the only way I have found is to use a right outer join, however that only works on two tables, I have one table and text data as the keys.

And before anyone asks...I cannot create a table to put this data in.

If it helps, this is an oracle 10g database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this.

first, get a public varrray of your choice ..theres usually quite a few about.

```
--pick a public VARRAY.
select owner, type_name from all_Coll_types where coll_type = 'VARYING ARRAY' 
and elem_type_name = 'VARCHAR2' ;
```

then select keeping the order of your IN list:

```
with numbers as (select /*+ cardinality(t, 10) */ rownum r, t.column_value pnumber
  from table(sys.dbmsoutput_linesarray('030390483', '089847547', '0347839874', '020983438')) t
)
select n.pnumber, m.mobile_number
  from numbers n
       left outer join mobilenumbers m
                    on n.pnumber = m.mobile_number
 order by n.r;
```

eg: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9da70/1

Comment: I think you're right, but is this behavior documented?  Can you prove that this will always be sorted, or is it possible that your query is just lucky?  You may want to take a look at this similar question, although I don't think the answer there really addresses the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13987855/409172

Comment: Thanks. Ended up doing something similar in a PL/SQL block. In the end it was 25 000 entries I had to process. Bring on the dba's!

Comment: @jonearles varrays have documented order [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF51007) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/collections.htm#i35815) (in fact i'd even say for a nested table when stored in-memory the order shouldn't change..only when its put to disk are all best off on NTs). also yes, that accepted answer is not right at all as they used `union` which would re-sort the array before passing to the table constructor (their result is precisely what i'd expect as you see its been ordered character wise).

Answer (score 0):

This is rather ugly but you can try:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM (SELECT 1 FROM DUAL) x
LEFT OUTER JOIN mobilenumbers ON mobile_number = '123456789'
UNION ALL
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM (SELECT 1 FROM DUAL) x
LEFT OUTER JOIN mobilenumbers ON mobile_number = '123456798'
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1570d/1)

Or, you can use this trick, but it may not maintain the order you specify the numbers in:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM TABLE(sys.odcivarchar2list('123456789','123456798')) x
LEFT OUTER JOIN mobilenumbers m ON x.COLUMN_VALUE = m.mobile_number
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1570d/3)

Comment: with 2500 mobile numbers, its going to be the mother of all queries...and might land me up in thedailywtf.com :-)

Comment: @Gerrie Very true although I'm not sure you have much of a choice if you can't create a table. I did add one more solution but it may not keep your ordering as you ask for in the title.

Comment: @Gerrie: you cannot have an `IN` operator with 2500 elements. The maximum is 1000 in Oracle.